# “No input file specified.” occurs when i remove index.php and admin.php in htaccess

Tags: codeigniter

here’s my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
AddType application/x-httpd-php53 .php
SetEnv TZ Asia/Manila
# If the user types just “admin”.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^admin$ admin\.php [L,QSA]
# If the user enter in any admin section, like “admin/section”.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^admin\/(.*)$ admin\.php/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

its all working fine on localhost but when i migrated to a live server this happens

Comment: In effect, you are saying that you remove both RewriteRule lines? You can't do that when you have RewriteCond there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume your trying to get rid of the 'index.php' in all your URL's for your codeigniter website. This is the .htaccess file I currently use and it works fine. For instance if my website URL is

www.test.com/index.php/home

It would come out as

www.test.com/home

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

If you'd like to have the word 'admin' act the same in your URL, write it like this below.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
RewriteRule .* admin.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

EDIT:

Also you mentioned the changes not working on your live server. Is your live web server running on windows?

If so, you need a 'web.config' file on the root of your website. This is what it should look like.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <configuration>
 <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Rewrite to index.php">
                <match url="index.php|robots.txt|images|test.php" />
                <action type="None" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Rewrite CI Index">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|htm|html|pdf|xls|xlsx" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```